# 504 ERROR , The request could not be satisfied

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s89Bf.png)CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

-- We are using aws and s3 instance.Please the attached image. i am trying to solve this but failed.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the answer here https://repost.aws/questions/QUT85-YuJFR-2tIhzprp8KTg/cloud-front-client-side-504-error
But this says that some users faced with it, some not.

We faced with the same. We enabled the logs on CloudFront panel.